# Implement Java aws lambda layers in serverless.yml

Tags: java, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-layers

I am looking for java solution to aws lambda layers in serverless.yml. I could easily see python, nodejs, .net implementations but couldn't find example for Java. Appreciate an example.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-samples.html

Comment: @Ashish Patil  that link is not relevant for this question. This is specifically looking for an example of lambda layers when using java and the Serverless Framework.

I second this question as I am also struggling to find a clear example of this. The quick reality is all a layer is is a java library. So it is possible to test this functionality locally by publishing your layer to maven local using shadowJar or the shade plugin. BUT... after you have tested locally it is not clear how to use the `serverless.yml` to get that layer uploaded.

Comment: I am able to reach the solution with maven using aws java layer. Utilizing it at other Java lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so [here](https://medium.com/consulner/speedup-aws-lambda-deployments-with-layers-12f8f24c7d0) is a rough answer. At least if you are not concerned with sharing the layers and if your not going for a minimal solution. For a more robust solution start by reading the above then do the following ... I have a whole project with multiple layers inside it - here is a screenshot of a single layer layout.

[image]

I think the thing that is most confusing in getting this to work right is everywhere talks about "zipping" the layer and while you can do that the process of zipping will only help you if you are intending to manually upload the layer. The linked blog post is partially/mostly correct but all that is actually needed is the `buildLayer` task. This will copy the dependencies to the build and make them available to serverless. To build the layer run `./gradlew clean build` ... this will result in

[image]

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id "java"                                                                                           // https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html
    id "idea"
    id 'io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving' version "$postCompileWeaving"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

/** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Dependencies: Configuration for dependencyManagement and dependency blocks.
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
dependencies {
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // PowerTools:
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    implementation "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:$aspectJrt"
    // WARNING!!! The exclusions in the following dependencies are assuming you are including all 4 of these PowerTools
    // dependencies. If you are not including all 4 then you should remove the exclusions and experiment yourself.
    // This is included to have greater control over the other PowerTools dependencies
    aspect ("software.amazon.lambda:powertools-core:$awsPowerTools") {
        exclude group: 'com.amazonaws', module: 'aws-lambda-java-core'
        exclude group: 'org.aspectj', module: 'aspectjrt'
    }
    aspect ("software.amazon.lambda:powertools-logging:$awsPowerTools") {
        exclude group: 'com.amazonaws', module: 'aws-lambda-java-core'
        exclude group: 'org.aspectj', module: 'aspectjrt'
        exclude group: 'software.amazon.lambda', module: 'powertools-core'
    }
    aspect ("software.amazon.lambda:powertools-metrics:$awsPowerTools") {
        exclude group: 'com.amazonaws', module: 'aws-lambda-java-core'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
        exclude group: 'org.aspectj', module: 'aspectjrt'
        exclude group: 'software.amazon.lambda', module: 'powertools-core'
    }
    aspect ("software.amazon.lambda:powertools-tracing:$awsPowerTools") {
        exclude group: 'com.amazonaws', module: 'aws-lambda-java-core'
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
        exclude group: 'software.amazon.awssdk', module: 'aws-core'
        exclude group: 'org.aspectj', module: 'aspectjrt'
        exclude group: 'software.amazon.lambda', module: 'powertools-core'
    }
}

// https://medium.com/consulner/speedup-aws-lambda-deployments-with-layers-12f8f24c7d0
// How to build the layer for serverless in a way it can reference
task buildLayer(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/layer/java/lib"
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
}

// AWS suggested way - this will build all the dependencies as a zip ready for manual
// upload to lambda BUT it can not be referenced by serverless.
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    into('lib') {
        from(jar)
        from(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    }
}

build.dependsOn buildLayer
```

**serverless.yml**

Now let serverless do its thing. Map the directory that has all the dependencies in it from gradle to a layer in the `serverless.yml` file. Now when you run `sls deploy --aws-profile default --verbose`. When you run the deploy command it will automatically zip the dependencies into the correct format for the lambda.

```
frameworkVersion: "3"
service: aws-powertools-layer

custom:                                                # Set custom options / variables for serverless
  serverlessPrefix: 'sls'                              # Short name for serverless

provider:
  name: aws                                             # Selected cloud provider
  runtime: java17                                       # Selected runtime
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}                            # Uses user specified stage (--stage VALUE) or defaults to dev
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-west-2'}                    # Uses user specified region (--region VALUE) or defaults to `us-west-2`
  deploymentBucket: # Collect all serverless deployment files in a single bucket
    name: YOUR-BUCKET-NAME                              # Specify bucket name
    serverSideEncryption: AES256                        # Specify bucket encryption
    maxPreviousDeploymentArtifacts: 10                  # Max number of old builds to keep

layers:
  powertools:
    path: build/layer
```

Once the serverless deploy is done it will return something like the following

```
layers:
  your-dependencies: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-X:XXXXXXXXX:layer:your-dependencies:1
```

You can then place that arn in your primary application `serverless.yml` file as follows

```
provider:
    ...
    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:us-west-X:XXXXXXXXX:layer:your-dependencies:1
```

and now your primary application can use the layer you have built.

***Note: There is no change required to your build.gradle dependencies block. This means you can still run your tests and everything else as normal***